# Groupby Column if Condition is fulfilled

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  0
3  3  0
4  4  1
```

I want to group by column b (as in groupby('b')), but only if simultaneously the values of column a are consecutive (monotonically increasing). E.g. the output should be:

```
Group 1: Row 0
Group 2: Row 1
Group 3: Row 2, 3
Group 4: Row 4
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand you, but your wording is totally wrong. You want to group by equal consecutive values in `b` and the same time monotonically increasing values in `a`?

Comment: I want to group by monotonically increasing values in a yes, and by equal values in column b.

Comment: Fix your wording, I think I have an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, construct temporary series based on your conditions -

```
i = df.a.eq(df.a.shift() + 1)         # monotonically increasing values in a
j = df.b.ne(df.b.shift()).cumsum()    # equal consecutive values in b
```

Now, call `groupby` -

```
for _, g in df.groupby([i, j]):
     print(g, '\n')

   a  b
0  0  0 

   a  b
1  1  1 

   a  b
2  2  0
3  3  0 

   a  b
4  4  1
```

---

**Details**

`i` is a series of bools, which says whether a value is monotonically increasing with respect to the element above.

```
i

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

`j` is a series that designates groups for consecutive values in `df.b`.

```
j

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    4
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is clever !

Comment: @MaxU Thank you!!